# rotation errors

Tags: objects

steps to reproduce: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rNWur2IW_RRuOhiCY84EdoMpMoOr0e8o/view?usp=sharing)

@markus-von-broady
[I brought one more circumstance. But unfortunately it was deleted, you did not see it.](https://i2.paste.pics/2bb7efa96ad7fd8332487742c2b5d786.png)

please reproduce this for yourself

[this project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kuoFV0tsNws0xdiFJSEEfKMgG-ulVrF_/view?usp=drive_link) is rotate to zero

[this project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZWVXeARmobCGL8Ca11N0l0IYZb07vduq/view?usp=drive_link) **does not** rotate to zero

what is the difference between projects? If there is no difference in projects - provide an example in which this strange effect can be clearly reproduced

You write about mathematics. But not about the "mechanics" of Blender.

I can use a calculator (in Python or anywhere) to do operations between two numbers. And if the initial data are the same, the answer will be the same. The result of the operation between A and B will always be the same: I cannot multiply 1.23456 by 2.34567 in a calculator to get 2.8958703552 the first time. And the second time will be something different. Is not it? In mathematics, this is impossible - this is confirmed in practice. This happens in Blender.

---

Comment: I can't tell you why it doesn't return exactly to zero. But will it being as it is make any noticeable difference to what you are going to do with this? There are 5 zeros between the decimal and the value. That value is 3 millionths of one degree.

Comment: A rotation transform involves multiplying matrices containing trig. calculations (sin and cos).. which are always approximations at the limit of floating-point resolution. Why not just enter '0' in the Rotation > X field, if that's what you want?

Comment: @curious_1
you are absolutely right. But the principle and logic of the program, it seems to me, would not hurt to know. Curious to know the fact - why sometimes it returns to zero

Comment: @Robin Betts
>>which are always approximations at the limit of floating-point resolution

means that sometimes it can turn out to be zero or even a little more than zero? But why do I always have the same value, slightly below zero?

Comment: @Robin Betts >>Why not just enter '0' in the Rotation > X field

before that I applied transformation→rotation for several objects. Changed various coordinates (both location and rotation). So I need to apply reverse transform→rotation. Entering zero in the field will not help.

Comment: Hi, @blenduser! .. OK, could you edit to flesh out your question with the exact sequence of steps leading up to the unexpected small value? (On the way, just in case, remember  the inverse of an XYZ Euler rotation is a ZYX Euler rotation.. you have to unwind in order)

Comment: Hi @robin-betts
[video with steps in the second line.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294210/rotation-errors-2)


Even lower - two .blend files

Answer (score 2):

I won't write an essay, because the question is unlikely to attract many visitors in future, but I'll elaborate on what Robin Betts already said in the comment.

Write in Python console:

```py
>>> sqrt(2**2)
2.0

>>> sqrt(2)**2
2.0000000000000004
```

In the first example first the number two is squared, which results with four. Simple. $4$ can be stored as the float64 Python uses for real numbers, so it's stored in memory in this form: `01000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`. The first bit `0` means the number is positive, the following 11 bits are the exponent, encoded as just like a typical signed integer is encoded, and it represents number 2, then the rest bits are mantissa and it's more complicated but basically it encoded a number between $1$ and $2$, with all zeroes meaning $1$, and all ones meaning $2$. Then you have a formula $\text{mantissa} \times2^{\text{exponent}}$ so in this case $1×2^{2} = 4$

Then you take a square root of that number, which is $1 × 2^{1} = 2$, this also can be stored in float64.

**2nd example:** First take square root of two: $\sqrt{2}=$
$1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621
07038850387534327641572735013846230912297024924836055850737212644121497099935831
41322266592750559275579995050115278206057147010955997160597027453459686201472851
74186408891986095523292304843087143214508397626036279952514079896872533965463318
08829640620615258352395054745750287759961729835575220337531857011354374603408498
84716038689997069900481503054402779031645424782306849293691862158057846311159666
87130130156185689872372352885092648612494977154218334204285686060146824720771435
85487415565706967765372022648544701585880162075847492265722600208558446652145839
88939443709265918003113882464681570826301005948587040031864803421948972782906410
45072636881313739855256117322040245091227700226941127573627280495738108967504018
36986836845072579936472906076299694138047565482372899718032680247442062926912485
90521810044598421505911202494413417285314781058036033710773091828693147101711116
83916581726889419758716582152128229518488472089694633862891562882765952635140542
26765323969461751129160240871551013515045538128756005263146801712740265396947024
03005174953188629256313851881634780015693691768818523786840522878376293892143006
55869568685964595155501644724509836896036887323114389415576651040883914292338113
20605243362948531704991577175622854974143899918802176243096520656421182731672625
75395947172559346372386322614827426222086711558395999265211762526989175409881593
48640083457085181472231814204070426509056532333398436457865796796519267292399875
36661721598257886026336361782749599421940377775368142621773879919455139723127406
68983299898953867288228563786977496625199665835257761989393228453447356947949629
52168891485492538904755828834526096524096542889394538646625744927556381964410316
97983306185201937938494005715633372054806854057586799967012137223947582142630658
51322174088323829472876173936474678374319600015921888073478576172522118674904249
77366929207311096369721608933708661156734585334833295254675851644710757848602463
60083444911481858765555428645512331421992631133251797060843655970435285641008791
85007603610091594656706768836055717400767569050961367194013249356052401859991050
62108163597726431380605467010293569971042425105781749531057255934984451126922780
34491350663756874776028316282960553242242695753452902883876844642917328277088831
80870253398523381227499908123718925407264753678503048215918018861671089728692292
01197599880703818543332536460211082299279293072871780799888099176741774108983060
80032631181642798823117154363869661702999934161614878686018045505553986913115186
01038637532500455818604480407502411951843056745336836136745973744239885532851793
08960373898915173195874134428817842125021916951875593444387396189314549999906107
58704909026088351763622474975785885836803745793115733980209998662218694992259591
32764236194105921003280261498745665996888740679561673918595728886424734635858868
64496822386006983352642799056283165613913942557649062065186021647263033362975075
69787060660685649816009271870929215313236828135698893709741650447459096053747279
65244770940992412387106144705439867436473384774548191008728862221495895295911878
92149179833981083788278153065562315810360648675873036014502273208829351341387227
68417667843690529428698490838455744579409598626074249954916802853077398938296036
21335398753205091998936075139064444957684569934712763645071632791547015977335486
38939423257277540038260274785674172580951416307159597849818009443560379390985590
16827215403458158152100493666295344882710729239660232163823826661262683050257278
11694510353793715688233659322978231929860646797898640920856095581426143636310046
15594332550474493975933999125419532300932175304476533964706627611661753518754646
20967634558738616488019884849747926404506544489691004079421181692579685756378488...$

Whoops! This is an irrational number, it can't be expressed as a ratio between two integers, therefore whatever integer you pick for your numeral system, you will only be able to approximate it - meaning you can take some digits, perhaps round the last taken digit up if it's followed by a high digit and call it a day. Float64 precision allows it to store the square root of 2 as:

$1.4142135623730951$

which in memory is stored as:

`00111111 11110110 10100000 10011110 01100110 01111111 00111011 11001101`

which can be interpreted in the form $\text{mantissa} \times2^{\text{exponent}}$:

$1.4142135623730951 ×2^{0}$

But hey, if we truncated (changed!) the result of our mathematical operation: $y = \text{changed}(\sqrt{2})$ then $y ≠ \sqrt{2}$ and so $y^{2} ≠ 2$ ❗

**The only reason why we could end up with the original number by squaring it, if by coincidence another error happened and it cancelled out the first error. It actually happens quite often:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.float16(np.power(np.sqrt(np.float16(2)), 2))
2.0
```

But apparently not in CPython for the default float64.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to give a definitive answer to this one.. I think you'd have to crack open the API, or even the source, and trace variables all the way through, to find out where the floating-point discrepancy occurs. However, a few observations:

- I **can't** reproduce the error, using the files provided, **unless** I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> copy the angle from the 'zero' file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> paste it into the 'not zero' file.  The visible representation of the number is therefore not the same as its internal representation, and there may be string-to-float conversions happening in one case and not the other?
- Plain <kbd>R</kbd> rotation (or Header > Transform > Rotate rotation,) defaults to rotation about View Z. Unless your objects are floating-point-perfectly aligned to the view, that is not the same as Local X, which is what is displayed in the Transform > Rotation panel. That's another possible source of inaccuracy. (For example, if at any point you've zeroed-out in one frame, that's not necessarily the same as zeroing-out in the other, to floating-point accuracy)
- It *is* possible to set  multiple objects' Local X rotation to 0 simultaneously in the Transform panel. With all objects selected, type '0' into the field, and return, while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Maybe at some point you will be rigging these objects, if not with an armature, then at least with a parenting hierarchy? Then, from a practical point of view, the anomaly will lose relevance.

Comment: @blenduser .. nice looking project, BTW :)

Comment: The displayed values in Blender have lower precision than the actual values stored in memory, that's why you can do `nextafter(inf, 0)` to get `inf` value, even though it's not real infinity, just a very large number (the largest possible float32 number) that rounds to infinity just for display purposes. I agree the not-so-perfect 'zeroing' of values is irrelevant unless it accumulates a lot (loops) or there's an exact epsilon-less comparison to 0 somewhere like in a shader…

Comment: @Robin Betts
it looks like you can reproduce the problem.
Copy into buffer memory the angle (Rotation X) from one file. And paste this data into a Windows notepad.
Then open another file. Do the same. Is this data different? Both files have the same value: 6.84502d Isn't it?

Comment: @Markus von Broady
does it mean there is a difference between the files?

How to get the data stored in memory to confirm, reproduce your version?

Comment: Hi, @blenduser! I did copy via a text-editor as part of my testing, and that reproduces the error.. since the text-editor shows the same precision as the Blender field, that suggests the (truncated) **string** is being pasted. Likewise between projects. If I copy-paste in the same project, I get no error, which suggests the underlying (higher precision) **value** is being pasted. I can't be sure, without looking, but that looks like a deferred choice of which representation of a value-object should be pasted. And the choice makes a difference to precision.

Comment: Hi @Robin Betts
could you record a video? [I copy and paste in the same project but the error persists](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rNWur2IW_RRuOhiCY84EdoMpMoOr0e8o/view?usp=drive_link)